# filter the variable in ansible output

Tags: filter, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to filter a variable from the output of one task in ansible. But the challenge is the I have the value of the variable and need to get the variable which is reverse.

Task from where I'm getting the below output.

```
    - uri:
      url: "https://*********/nics/nic1"
        method: GET
        force_basic_auth: true
        headers:
          cookie: "{{ login.cookies_string }}"
        validate_certs: false
      register: test
```

Output :-

```
    ok: [192.168.84.203] => {
        "allow": "GET, PUT", 
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "status_code": [
                    200
                ],
            }
        }, 
        "json": {
            "body": {
                "interfaces": {
                     "@order": [
                         "ff7574025754b3df1647001"
                     ], 
                     "ff7574025754b3df1647001": {
                         "addresses": {
                             "1": "192.168.1.4/22", 
                             "@order": [
                                 "1"
                             ]
                         }, 
                         "mtu": 1500, 
                         "name": "default", 
                         "source_based_routes": [], 
                         "vlantag": 0
                     }
                }, 
           }
           }
        }
    }
```

The above output has 1: 192.168.1.3/22 from which i need to retrieve "1" where I have 192.168.1.4/22 handy.
It's basically a reverse from what we do regularly. Appreciate your help here.

I have tried a task as below, but it's not working.

```
    - name: find key
      vars:
        key_list: >-
          {{ 
            body.interfaces
            | dict2items
            | selectattr('value.addresses', 'defined')
            | map(attribute='value.addresses')
            | map('dict2items')
            | flatten
            | selectattr('value', 'eq', rl_ip)
            | map(attribute='key')
          }}
      debug:
        msg: "This is the key:{{ key_list }}"
```

Final Output :

```
    TASK [find key] *********************************************************************************
    ok: [192.168.84.203] => {
    "msg": "This is the key: <generator object do_map at 0x7fe0a693fc80>"
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to find a dict key corresponding to a given value it contains. The difficulty here is that it is nested in a higher level structure and that you might have several results in the same dict.

*Side Note for your next question*: please don't give truncated output that people have to rebuild to test and give examples in their answers: create an [MCVE](/help/mcve)

In a nutshell, the following playbook example should give the expected result (if I correctly understood your data structure from your truncated example)

**Update**: since your data comes from a `uri` task returning the http call in a `json` key and that you register that task result in a variable called `test` I updated my below example to match your situation.

```yaml
---
- name: Find key demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # This is what you data looks like after the uri call
    test:
      json:
        "body": {
          "interfaces": {
            "@order": [
                "ff7574025754b3df1647001"
            ],
            "ff7574025754b3df1647001": {
              "addresses": {
                "1": "192.168.1.4/22",
                "@order": [
                    "1"
                ]
              },
              "mtu": 1500,
              "name": "default",
              "source_based_routes": [ ],
              "vlantag": 0
            }
          }
        }

    # this is what we are looking for
    needle_in_haystack: "192.168.1.4/22"

  tasks:
    - name: find key(s) in haystack for given needle
      vars:
        key_list: >-
          {{
            test.json.body.interfaces
            | dict2items
            | selectattr('value.addresses', 'defined')
            | map(attribute='value.addresses')
            | map('dict2items')
            | flatten
            | selectattr('value', 'eq', needle_in_haystack)
            | map(attribute='key')
            | list
          }}
      debug:
        msg: "This is the list of found keys: {{ key_list }}"
```

And the result:

```
PLAY [Find key demo] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [find key(s) in haystack for given needle] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "This is the list of found keys: ['1']"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator, Thanks for the reply. I tried with above solution but it's not working. I am adding the Error and the code i tried in the question. Please do the needful.

Comment: How are you loading the data you give in your example? Please make this all thing [MCVE](/help/mcve) as already asked.

Comment: I am getting this data as a output from previous task from which i'm trying to filter.@Zeitounator  Added the complete output from the previous task in the question for your reference.

Comment: Updated the output clearly from the previous task. please advise..! thanks in advance..

Comment: How did you register that output? The data from the task output is one thing. The task itself producing that output is an other. Both are needed to help you.

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator, Added Task that produces the output. Please check it once and advise..

Comment: Updated to match  your situation. Meanwhile it looks like you are sending a uri call to a network device to get info. Are you aware there are numerous module available to manage that for you? Are you sure your network device is not already supported?

Comment: This does pass through but doesn't give the value of the key we are expecting..! @Zeitounator

Comment: There was a small indentation error making my example fail. Meanwhile, I do find (as shown in my run example) the result you expect using the exact same data you shown in your question. If this is not the case for your, you have a different data. You now have to find why and debug to find a solution. Good luck,

Comment: I have updated the latest output i am getting. The data is exactly same as the  above furnished one. It's syntactically correct as well.  Can you check this output once.

Comment: And this is a brilliant demonstration of why "doesn't work" / "not giving the expected value" is not an accurate description of your problem. Now that you gave the exact behaviour / output the solution is easy. Updated my answer with a version that will work in both ansible < 2.10 and >= 2.10.

Comment: Thank you so much@Zeitounator, That really worked and I'm able to run now

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, i need some help again. Here we are printing 1 which is good. I have a situation where i need to filter the order value "ff7574025754b3df1647001" with respect to this ip..! Could you please advise how i can achieve it. Thanks in advance..@Zeitounator

Comment: SO is not a chat service. This is an other question. Create an [MCVE](/help/MCVE) and ask a new one.

Comment: Okay..! Added an another question..! Could you please check it and  answer for me ? Since you are aware of the background.